# User decryption/encryption in PHP | storing key in session

Tags: php, session, encryption

so I have this website that allows users to write every day. It then get stocked in a database in **plain text**. It's not a blog so everything is private, and the biggest complain I regularly get is that "I" could still read what they wrote. It was still not "perfectly" private. Also I don't want to be the one who leaked thousand of private diaries.

So here is my train of thought on how to rend it private only to them.

- When they log in : key = sha1(salt + password) and store this key in a SESSION (how secure is that ?)
- When they save their text : encrypt it with their $_SESSION['key'] before saving it to the database
- When they read something they've saved, decrypt it with their $_SESSION['key'] before displaying it.

Is that secure ? Also what is the best way to encrypt/decrypt UTF-8 ?

Also if someone changes its password it has to decrypt/re-crypt everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead store the hash of the password in the SESSION.
**Never store plain passwords anywhere - anywhere!!**

Also, consider reading this stackoverflow thread: [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

To hash the password, you can use this approach:

- Generate a salt for a particular user (a salt is a random string of characters), and store it somewhere, or generate a global salt (in your use case)
- Use the following function to generate a hash for the password, and store that hash in the SESSION

---

```
function generate_hash($password) {
   $salt = "<some random string of characters>"; // do not change it later.
   return md5($salt . $password);
}
```

---

For the encryption, you can use the [mCrypt](https://www.php.net/mcrypt) library. A typical algorithm can be:

```
$key = 'password to (en/de)crypt';
$string = 'string to be encrypted';

$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

var_dump($encrypted);
var_dump($decrypted);
```

Comment: But what algorithm should I use in mcrypt ? Texts are usually > 750 words

Answer (score 1):

You should be using some form of encryption.  PHP provides [mCrypt](https://www.php.net/mcrypt) for this purpose.  Point by Point:

1. Saving a password in the clear in a $_SESSION is inherently insecure.  At the very least, [hash it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) in both the session and the database.  Then you can compare the hashes to one another.  Sensitive data should never be stored in the clear *anywhere*.
2. You can simplify this by using mCrypt.  However, I think the focus here is incorrect.  Rather than hashing all of this "diary" text, I think you should be more focused on abstracting the *user information* from the text itself.
3. No need to use their password.  Just use a common key and use `mcrypt` for this.

I hope this helps!

Comment: > abstracting the user information from the text itself.
what do you mean ?

Comment: Abstraction simply means separation - or exclusion.  Don't make it easy to see which user posted which data.

Comment: there can be a lot of important information in the text, no matter who wrote it. I don't think it's a good idea in my case. But thanks.

Comment: The rest of the advice still applies.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use password to encrypt the key, password should never be used anywhere in the logic, and should only be read on login as a hash not plain text. You can user other things like user email to generate a key.